# Increment the value of a cell by 1 after checking values in a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I know this is as trivial and easy as it gets, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I am completely clueless when it comes to excel formulas.

[[image: Sheet image for reference][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgqEA.jpg)

I would like the cell U7 to increment by 1 for each "D" it finds in the selected range of cells (E7:S7), same with the cell V7, increment by 1 but for each "N" it finds in the same range of cells.

I was trying to use multiple if statements like:

```
=IF(E7:S7="D";1;0)
```

But that doesn't seem to work at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are after. Use COUNTIF to count the number of times D or N occur in your range.

```
=COUNTIF(E7:S7,"D")
```

Comment: Damn, I was just a bit too late :D

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, knew it had to be mad obvious! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `COUNTIF()`-Function:

```
=COUNTIF(E7:S7, "D")
```

For more reference, see the Microsoft Office [support site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `=COUNTIF()` Function.

You referred to `VBA`, so I assume you want to run this in a program possibly.

The code below will run through the used rows starting in row 7 and then insert the number of 'D" letters seen in the columns E to S.

```
 Sub CountNumberOfDLetters()

      Dim LastRow As Long
      With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
          LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
      End With

      Dim RowReference As Long
      Dim DataRange As Range
      Dim NumberOfD As Double

      For RowReference = 7 To LastRow

           Set DataRange = Range(Cells(RowReference, "E"), Cells(RowReference, "S"))
           NumberOfD = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(DataRange, "D")
           Cells(RowReference, "U").Value = NumberOfD

      Next RowReference

 End Sub
```